# Global mixins fired multiple times - Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I've created a mixin to change the page titles, using `document.title` and global mixins.

My mixin file (title.ts):

```
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

function getTitle(vm: any): string {
  const title: string = vm.title
  if (title) {
    return `${title} | site.com`
  }
  return 'Admin panel | site.com'
}

@Component
export default class TitleMixin extends Vue {
  public created(): void {
    const title: string = getTitle(this)
    if (title) {
      document.title = title
    }
  }
}
```

Then i registered this mixin globally in main.ts:

```
import titleMixin from '@/mixins/title'
Vue.mixin(titleMixin)
```

Then setting up the title in a Vue component:

```
@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
  public title: string = 'New title'
}
```

I have like 5 components in my project, if i use `console.log` in a mixin, i can see that it fired in every component, step by step, thus `document.title` is set by a last component `created()` hook.

How to correctly set a title for a CURRENT page?

Comment: You should take a look at https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta

Comment: Regarding your question, most probably you are not lazy loading the views, so the `created` life-cycle hook in each view is called, that's why the last one is setting the `document.title`. Try using the `mounted` hook instead.

Comment: @Ricky, the thing is, i'm actually using lazy load in the project: `component: () => import('@/views/Login.vue')`. I still don't get it, why `created()` is fired for every component, shouldn't it be fired only for the current one? By the way, you were right, in `mounted()` it fired just once. Going to read lifecycles again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, a global mixin will affect every component in your Vue app, which means that the logic to set the `document.title` will fire in the `created` hook of every component in your app.

I think what you're looking for is VueRouter's `beforeRouteEnter` hook, which is [one of the navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) that the library makes available to any of your components. A component's `beforeRouteEnter` hook fires immediately before the route changes to whichever one it's associated with.

In your case it would look like this:

```
@Component
export default class TitleMixin extends Vue {
  public beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next): void {
    next(vm => {
      const title: string = getTitle(vm)
      if (title) {
        document.title = title
      }
    })
  }
}
```

You'll notice that the `next` function (which needs to be called for the route to resolve) is being passed a callback which has a reference to the component's instance (`vm`), which we're passing to `getTitle` instead of `this`. This is necessary because the `beforeRouteEnter` hook does not have a reference to `this`. You can read the docs I linked to for more info.

Comment: As @ricky pointed me out, issue was with `created()` hook, seems like it's fired even if you're using lazy load. Your variant is viable as well, but it's involving in a `Component.registerHooks` to use `beforeRouterEnter` in a class, thus it's more of unnecessary code in my case :D Could you explain instead, why `created()` is fired for every component in my case?

Comment: @AlexanderKim, yes the `created` hook is always fired when a component is created whether it's lazy-loaded or not. The issue is that you are using a global mixin to specify that at the moment each component in your app is created, it should run your logic to set the document title. I would expect that @ricky's suggestion to use `mounted` would face the same issue, although I'm not sure how you are initializing your router views.

Comment: actually `mounted()` is fired just once. My router is pretty standard from Vue-CLI 3 generator. Any ideas? You can test yourself on a clean project, it's in fact fires on every single component if you're using global mixin and `created()` lifecycle.

Comment: If you are saying you are now using a global mixin to specify a function to run in the `mounted` hook for every component and that function is only running once, then that means you have only mounted a single component in your app. I would expect that when you change routes, the `mounted` hook for the associated component will call that function again. Hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: Well, `mounted()` is fired when a component is actually mounted, i.e. when i visit the page, in my case `Login.vue`. So, when i visit `Login.vue` - my title changed to "LOGIN", when i leave this component - it gets `destroyed()`, and new component `Dashboard.vue` is `mounted()`. It's logically correct now. But i thought, `created()` hooks worked the same way. That's odd.

Comment: Yeah it seems like something specific to how your project is set up.

Comment: Maybe it's because i'm using vue-property-decorator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193347/discussion-between-thanksd-and-alexander-kim).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a global mixin, try using a [route meta field](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) along with a [global resolve guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-resolve-guards).

First, we'll start by adding a meta field to each `RouteConfig` in the `/router/routes.ts` file:

```
import { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'

export default [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'login-view' */ '@views/Login.vue'),
    meta: {
      title: 'Login', // Set the view title
    },
  },
  // ... Add the title meta field to each `RouteConfig`
] as RouteConfig[]
```

Then, we'll create a global resolve guard, to set the title meta field as the document title, in the `/router/index.ts` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router, { Route } from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  // ... RouterOptions
})

// Before each route resolves...
// Resolve guards will be called right before the navigation is confirmed,
// after all in-component guards and async route components are resolved.
router.beforeResolve((routeTo, routeFrom, next) => {

  const documentTitle = getRouteTitle(routeTo)

  // If the `Route` being navigated to has a meta property and a title meta field,
  // change the document title
  if (documentTitle ) {
    document.title = documentTitle 
  }

  // Call `next` to continue...
  next()

  function getRouteTitle(route: Route): string {
    const title: string = route.meta && route.meta.title
    if (title) {
      return `${title} | site.com`
    }
    return 'Admin panel | site.com'
  }
})

export default router
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the mixin only in the parent component for your page (the one that holds all the page itself).

Using your `vue-property-decorator` should be in this way:

```
import { Vue, Component, Mixins } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Login extends Mixins(titleMixin) {
  public title: string = 'New title'
}
```

And do not import it globally with `Vue.mixin(titleMixin)`. In this way it is imported for all the components.

Comment: I need to import it in all components, that's why i'm using `Vue.mixin()` in a main file.